C++ vector constructed directly as range argument not working as expected
This is different when I construct a vector directly as an argument vs. using one defined as a variable, can someone explain why?
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <std::ranges::range R>
std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R> random_elt(R&& r) {
    auto it = r.begin();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ::rand() % std::ranges::size(r); i++) {
        it++;
    }
    return it;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};

    // This is fine.
    cout << *random_elt(v) << endl;

    // Surely this should be the same?
    cout << *random_elt(std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3})) << endl;
}

Error:
$ g++ -o main main.cpp -std=gnu++23
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:24:13: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<std::vector<int> >’)
   24 |     cout << *random_elt(std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3})) << endl;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Your function template random_elt accepts the range by reference and returns an iterator into it.
The first case is OK because the range is based on the std::vector v whose lifetime exceeds the usage of the output from random_elt.
But in the second case the argument std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3}) is a temporary. The iterator into the range based on it that you return from random_elt is potentially dangling. You attempt to dereference it with operator* when the range's lifetime has potentially ended.
The error from gcc that you posted is a bit unintuitive, but it mentions std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t which is related to potentially dangling iterators.
MSVC in this case issues a clearer error message and mentions std::ranges::dangling:
error C2100: you cannot dereference an operand of type 'std::ranges::dangling'

Live demo with MSVC error

Aren't temporaries only destroyed at the end of a full expression in C++? The temporary std::vector<int> ought to still be valid at the point the iterator is dereferenced.

I am not a language lawyer, so I'm not 100%. But based on observation I think the full expression in this case is the argument passed to the function itself (not the one containing the dereferencing of the result) because of the range that is constructed from the vector. During the function execution the temporary is bound to the reference (the parameter R&& r) and its lifetime is extended, but not afterwards.

No, that's definitely not right.  std::clamp for example takes references and returns references, and I can definitely write cout << clamp(3, 1, 5) << endl;, or even cout << clamp(1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 + 6) << endl;.

@Bernard as I wrote above I thought it has something to do with the range that is created from the temp vector, since MSVC seems very clear about the dangling iterator. If you have a different explanation please share it (or even edit my answer if you like). BTW - note that gcc's error mentions std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t which according to the documentation also related to potential dangling iterator (and the same page also mentions  ranges::dangling which is mentioned in MSVC's error.

@Bernard I edited my answer, hopfully is it more accurate now. Again feel free to correct me/it.
